# What could be wrong with my "push" argument and my to-do-app css?

Tags: css, push

The problem is my cancel div doesn't appear when i click the "add-note" button and also when i type the data into the title field and note field and hit submit the console announce the mistake as "cannot read the property "push" of null". What could be wrong?
This is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="notes.css">
    
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="add-note">
        <a href="#myModel" class="add-note">Add note</a>
    </div>
    <div class="model" id="myModel">
        <div class="model-content">
            <h1 class="header">Add note</h1>
            <form class="note-form" action="">
                <label for="">Title</label></br>
                <input class="title" type="text"></br>
                <label for="">Note</label></br>
                <input class="note" type="text"></br>
                <input type="submit">
                <div class="cancel">
                    <a href="#close" class="cancel-btn">Cancel</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </br>
    <table class="note-table">
        <tr>
            <td class="header">Title</td>
            <td class="note">Note</td>
        </tr>
    </table>>
    
    <script src="note.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my js file:

```
let model=document.querySelector('.model')
let noteForm=document.querySelector('.note-form')
let noteTable=document.querySelector('.note-table')
let cancel= document.querySelector('.cancel-btn')

let noteDeleteButtons
let noteList=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes'))

if (noteList!==null){
    appendNotes()
}

noteForm.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
    addNote(e)
    
})
function addNote(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    

    let newNote={}

    let title=document.querySelector('.title')
    let note=document.querySelector('.note')
    if(title.value=="" || note.value=="blank"){
        return alert('pls enter both fields')
    }else{
        newNote.title=title.value
        newNote.note=note.value

    }
    title.value=""
    note.value=""

    noteList.push(newNote)
    appendNotes()
    cancel.click()
    
}
function appendNotes(){
    let notes=Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.noteItem'))
    if (notes.length>0){
        notes.forEach(note=>{
            note.remove()
        })
    }
    noteList.map(note=>{
        // create table cells
        let tr=document.createElement('tr')
        tr.classList="noteItem"
        let tdTitle=document.createElement('td')
        tdTitle.innerText=note.title;
        let tdNote=document.createElement('td')
        tdNote.innerText=note.note;
        let tdDelete=document.createElement('td')
        tdDelete.innerHTML="&times"
        tdDelete.classList.add("delete-item")
        //append tables cell
        tr.appendChild(tdTitle)
        tr.appendChild(tdNote)
        tr.appendChild(tdDelete)
        //append row to table
        noteTable.appendChild(tr)
        getDeleteButtons()
        localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(noteList))
    })
}
function getDeleteButtons(){
    noteDeleteButtons=Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.delete-item'))
    noteDeleteButtons.forEach(button=>{
        let noteTitle=button.previousSibling.previousSibling.innerText;
    button.addEventListener('click',()=>{
            console.log(noteTitle)
        })
    })

}
```

This is my css file:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
a{
    color:white;
}
.add-note{
    position: relative;
    background-color:blue;
    color:black;
    width: 8rem;
    padding:0.5rem;
    border-radius:5px;
    left:10%;
    top:5%;
}
.add-note:hover{
    opacity:0.7;
}
input{
    margin-bottom:1rem;
    border:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid blue;
}
.model{
    position: fixed;
    top:-20%;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    padding:1.5rem;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index:9999;
    opacity:0;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in;
    border-radius:5px;

}
.model:target{
    opacity:1;
    top:0;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```